# ionic - `slot` attributes are deprecated - eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, eslint, vetur

I am getting following error in VS Code:

```
[vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute]
`slot` attributes are deprecated. eslint-plugin-vue
```

[image]

I have these two plugin installed in `.eslintrc.js`

```
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
```

And this in rules:

```
'vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute': 'off',
```

What should be done in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: What do you want to do with that `<ion-refresher>` component/element? Do you want to inject it into an existing slot (named "fixed") of its parent component (the `<ion-content>`)? (That seems to be your intention right now.) Or do you want to create a new slot named "fixed" as a child of the `<ion-refresher>` element, so that the consumers of the component that you are creating here will be able to inject custom HTML into the `<ion-refresher>`'s content?

Comment: @BartHofland I don't know what exactly does do the slot="fixed" do. I am new to `ionic` and `vue`. I found in the ionic doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher that you have to add that attribute in the code otherwise the `ion-refresher` is not working properly. I think i has something to do with the designing rather than inject anything in the code

Comment: I see... I looked at the info in your link. It indeed seems to be the case that Ionic's `<ion-content>` element has a slot called "fixed", so it should be perfectly valid to inject that `<ion-refresher>` element into it. But since the `slot` attribute is obsolete in Vue now, I tend to agree with [tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151)'s answer to replace the obsolete syntax `slot="fixed"` with the new Vue-syntax `v-slot:fixed`. It seems that tony19 made some edits to his answer lately. Perhaps it will work for you now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This slot actually refers to webcomponent slots;
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/22236

> The slots Ionic Framework uses are not the same as Vue 2 slots. The slots we use are Web Component slots and are valid usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots.

> Developers should be using the Web Component slots to position elements as per our docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range#usage

Check to ensure your eslint.js has the following rule:

```
  rules: {
    'vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute': 'off',
  }
```

Next open .vscode/settings.json and add the following:

```json
  "vetur.validation.template": false,
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this thing: `"vetur.validation.template": false,`?
Is it going to disable the vue validator ?

Comment: https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/linting-error.html#error-checking

it will rely on eslint to do the checking instead.

Comment:  VSCode toolbar select Code -> preferences -> settings + search "template" uncheck Vetur > Validation -> Template

Answer (score 6):

#### Warning about slots

The [`vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-slot-attribute.html) warning is really about the [`slot` attribute in Vue templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax), which were replaced with `v-slot`. However, since Ionic Web components use the native [`slot` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/slot), you can safely ignore the warning, or disable it:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute': 'off',
  }
}
```

If using VS Code with Vetur, disable Vetur's template validation, which ignores `.eslintrc.js`. The Vetur [docs recommend using the ESLint Plugin](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/linting-error.html#linting) to configure your own ESLint rules:

> If you want to config ESLint rules, do the following:
>
> - Turn off Vetur's template validation with `vetur.validation.template: false`
> - Make sure you have the [ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). The errors will come from ESLint plugin, not Vetur.
> - `yarn add -D eslint eslint-plugin-vue` in your workspace root
> - Set ESLint rules in `.eslintrc`.

#### Unused `fixed`

Regarding the `'fixed' is defined but never used` error you [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913547/ionic-slot-attributes-are-deprecated-eslint-plugin-vue/65914100?noredirect=1#comment116540986_65913760), your `<script>` section in the SFC likely has an unused variable named `fixed`. Simply remove that variable to resolve the error.

Answer (score 5):

you can try add this on .vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "vetur.validation.template": false
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this code. could you please explain this !

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use old syntax which is really [deprecated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-with-the-slot-Attribute). Try to use [named slots syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots).

So, I guess instead of

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed">...</ion-refresher>
```

you should use

```
 <ion-refresher>
  <slot name="fixed">...</slot>
 </ion-refresher>
```

Comment: It shows this error in console: `Make sure you use: <ion-refresher slot="fixed">`

Answer (score -1):

Just use `// eslint-disable-next-line` OR `eslint-disable-line` to disable eslint on the next line containing the slot tag and move on with the code, if you wish to continue with that same code

OR

you can use `<template v-slot>` for using a unnamed slot tag and
`<template v-slot="name>` to use named slot tag.

here is the link to the doc [Link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-abusive-eslint-disable.md#enforce-specifying-rules-to-disable-in-eslint-disable-comments),

Comment: It shows `'fixed' is defined but never used.` if using 2nd solution

Comment: 'Fixed' must be some args used in a vue component method but which you never used inside the method.

Comment: I am using the slot for designing the page.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher

Comment: This issue is with es-lint formater i think simply disable the es-lint on this page to move on with the existing code or update the es-lint config file 
use the Link to configure the es-lint rule inside of your .eslint.js file

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments